# nslookup shows record has updated, but it hasn't for any of my devices

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I had a record **store.example.com** which was set up as URL Redirect to **foo.bar.com**. 14 hours ago, I changed this record to a CNAME record to point to **qux.bar.com**.

Now, nslookup shows that the record has updated just fine. However, all of my devices still lead to the wrong website when I type in **store.example.com** in their browsers. I have already tried flushing DNS, restarting PC, changing DNS resolver. What am I missing?

Comment: It might not be a DNS issue but browser related instead and the following Q&A on Stack Overflow might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s

Comment: Hmm, I really thought you had me there, but the old URL redirect was a 302, not a 301. I've also tried clearing my browser cache and verified that it was empty, but still leads to the old address.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't exactly know what is causing this, but I changed the CNAME record to a URL redirect record, and now it works fine. I think it had something to do with CNAME chain.